# Android animation - frame-by-frame?

Tags: android, animation, loops, frame, drawable

So, I'm new to programming with android and one of the first thing I'm trying to do is create a basic animation that starts on its own. Nothing complicated, just a looping animation. I am trying to stick with frame-by-frame because it seems the most basic and easiest to understand. I have looked at many tutorials/websites/videos (including the android dev sites) on how to do this and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm sure I have a simple logic error somewhere. Below is my posted code. Can someone help me out? Thank you for the help!  (Also, as a side note this is specifically running on a NookColor emulator, according to Nook Developer site, the nook runs the latest android. Unfortunately the Nook site gives no tutorials or anything useful, only the same links to Android developers.)

```
//main class

public class WallpaperActivity extends Activity {

    AnimationDrawable animSequence;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ImageView animImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.animatepic);
        animImg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation);
        animSequence = (AnimationDrawable) animImg.getBackground();

    }


    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
    {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        animSequence.start();
    }
}


//animation.xml  class ( << this is not my main.xml class)

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/animatepic" android:oneshot="false" >

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/b" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/c" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/d" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/e" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/f" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/g" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/h" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/i" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/j" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/k" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/l" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/m" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/n" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/o" android:duration="200" />
    </animation-list>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error or your animation is not getting started...

Comment: The only feedback I got was the emulator would load up and then it would say the app had to be "Forced Closed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you say what error you were getting?

In any case, your code example seems to have been [updated](http://www.twintechs.com/blog/?p=35).

Here is its [zip file](http://www.twintechs.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/06/xmlanimation.zip) you can download.

Comment: Thanks for the code Stephan, that really helped me. I realized what my error was and of course it was a simple over-looked piece of code. In my posted animation.xml class, I gave the animation set the id of animatepic, then I try to reference it in the WallPaperActivity. Instead I should have been referencing the ImageView object in my main.xml file...Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView animImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.animatepic);
animImg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation);
animSequence = (AnimationDrawable) animImg.getBackground();
animSequence.start();
```

try this